# Divergence and Convergence of improper integrals of $1/x$ and $1/x^2$

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Prove that $\int_1^\infty dx/x $ diverges and $\int_1^\infty dx/x^{2} $ converges

I think that the former, $dx/x$ converges as plugging the bounds doesn't yield a non-existent result.

Comment: Consider comparing the first integral to the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty\frac 1x$.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you ask a question, don't spare with the "?" marks... :-)

Comment: @abiessu That's really the hard way. And you really want $\frac{1}{i}$, perhaps?

Comment: @thomasandrews: that is what I meant.  This habit I have of throwing out the first suggestion that comes to mind isn't really working very well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First integral: 
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{1}^{t} \frac{dx}{x}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\ln(t)-\ln(1)=\infty.
$$
Second:
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{1}^{t} \frac{dx}{x^2}=\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{-t}-\frac{1}{-1}=1.
$$